# Developer/Designer asking for admin access

Tags: wp-admin, security

I have a Wordpress website and want a customized home-page built with Elementor plugin for my website. I am not good at designing attractive pages so I contacted one small firm to help me out with designing the home-page but they are asking me for the admin access so that they can use Elementor for page building. I am not comfortable giving them the admin access as they could have all control of my website and therefore could try to harm the website (I am just saying).

So is there a better way to get the job done without compromising security? I have also searched through the questions before asking but found no definite answer. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The professional way would be for them to work on a copy of your website set up in their own servers.

This means that you should give them all the ftp files + the related DB. Then they work on their website and when the work is done you can update your website.

If you want professionals working on your website of course you should be able to trust them. If you don't trust them move on to a more reliable provider.

Another way would be to give them access to your admin and in case something bad happens you can just contact your hosting and ask to revert to a backup. 
Before starting of course you should do that backup.
But in my opinion this is not professional at all and should be avoided.

I would also avoid to hire them just to use Elementor. It may be a waste of money. If they customize your website with elementor + css and maybe some JS to actually improve it and make it unique that's okay, but if coding is not involved hiring an agency is a waste of money. You could just "hire" a virtual assistant able to use Elementor.

But again, I would still avoid it, because to properly improve a website you will need a professional to keep the performance on check.

Comment: Well, I get it that hiring them just to customize with Elementor is a waste of money, and I do know how to use Elementor but I am not at all good with designing flashy attractive web pages. And it is not just customizing, I am also hiring them for image editing and stuff. To put it simply, I just need a good designer, that is why I thought it might be a good idea to hire them. Any thoughts on WordPress Staging?

Comment: the staging should be their responsibility in my opinion, however I see that your situation is particular. You could ask to your hosting if you have an option to setup a sub-domain and let them work there. It's a little bit technical but not too complicated. Keep in mind that you should take some precautions to not let the staging being indexed by google and other search engines. However this is a topic for another question :)

Answer (score 0):

All of the top 3 WordPress Hosting providers support staging. Just check your hosting/plan first and see if there is something available for you. If you have [everything up and running](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-staging-environment-for-a-wordpress-site/) just give them access to the development site.

If you're from europe, please don't forget the data processing agreement according to the GDPR.